# autocomplete options causes dropdown login box to vanish

Tags: javascript, css

I have a dropdown login box that displays when you hover over it, it works fine, however if the user double clicks in the username field for example to show the selections and then hovers down the login box will vanish.

Shouldn't really be much of an issue since they should only have the one username, but if there is a quick fix available that would be good.

Example [here](http://condorstudios.com/stuff/temp/so/header-sample.php)

[Another site](http://www.dynadot.com/) that has this issue:

**Edit:** Seems to work fine in Chrome.

Comment: I can't see the problem in Chrome.

Comment: @ralph.m I usually use FF, just tried chrome and you're right, it doesn't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from user "coma" on another question that seemed to fix this issue:

```
$(function() {

    var dropdown = $('div.login div.dropdown')
        .on('focus', 'input', function() {

            dropdown.css('display', 'block');
        })
        .on('blur', 'input', function() {

            dropdown.removeAttr('style');
        });
});
```